# How to disable form value persistence on page reload for Firefox

Tags: firefox

When I type some data in to a form `input type="text"` field, and then refresh the page in Firefox the values are remembered and the default values are not restored. This is not what I want to have happen; Google Chrome does reload the default values and wipes whatever I typed; So **how do I disable this?**

Answer (score 9):

add autocomplete="off" in the form, or the text field

Answer (score 0):

Go:

1. Type `about:config` into the URL bar (continue past the safety statement that may pop up if you haven't yet disabled it)
2. In the `filter` search box at the top of the page, type `browser.startup.page`
3. Set the first value (with the name `browser.startup.page`, not anything longer) to `"3"`

Hope this helps

---

See [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.startup.page) for a description of `browser.startup.page`

See [here](http://lifehacker.com/209941/geek-to-live--top-firefox-2-config-tweaks) for the source of the fix (did it myself a while ago)

Finally, see [here](http://lifehacker.com/396312/power-users-guide-to-firefox-3) and [here](http://lifehacker.com/5041335/useful-firefox-3-configuration-tweaks) for two other "Firefox config hacks"

Comment: How is this relevant to the persistence of form values between page reloads?